# How to query accumulative counter increase with PromQL?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have created a **Promethues Counter** which is exposed in multiple hosts. I want to know the trend of the **sum of the counter from all hosts**.

- If I simply use the `sum (counter_name{some condition})`, this will be incorrect when some host is shutdown or restarted.
- If I use the `increase`, there should be specify a time range, which will only show the increase of every interval. (It can't calculate the increasement from a same start time point to the time of every point in the time serial.)

Is there any way to accumulate all the increase result from a specific time point?

[image]

---

I find there's a workaround method to get a plot like what I want:

```
sum(increase (demo_total[1y]))
```

[image]

The expression means I should set a **large time range**, which will lead Prometheus to calc the increasement of every time value to 0 (the counter is zero when it was not exposed ever)

If I want to calc the increase from a specific time, I just need to minus the `increase` result at a timestamp:

```
sum(increase (demo_total[1y])) - sum(increase (demo_total[1y] @1690439160))
```

[image]

**I think this is an ugly way and I also wonder it's low effective. Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Maybe example of values and expected result could help.

Comment: @markalex thanks for your response. I append a picture to illustrate what I want

Comment: Thanks for clarification. No there is no better, nor more efficient way for this. Additionally, you'll eventually have problems with old values described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76663450). This is the way things are in promql.

Comment: @markalex Thank you for the direction to the question and the answer. My question seem quite same with the one you've given. So I'll close this.